# Setting a global option for all forms in a Laravel application

Tags: php, forms, oop, laravel, laravel-4

I want all forms in my laravel application to have 'autocomplete' => 'off' by default, unless I specify 'autocomplete' => 'on'..

Since my application has many forms and laravel is such an awesome framework, I am wondering if I can set a global option of the form class to be always autocomplete off unless I specify the opposite.

Anyone know about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  The basic idea is that you need to extend two classes: the built in `Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder` and `Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider` classes, and replace the `HtmlServiceProvider` in `app/config/app.php` with the one you create.

First, create a `MyForm` class that is going to override the functionality you want from the `FormBuilder`:

```
use Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder;

class MyForm extends FormBuilder
{
    /**
     * Open up a new HTML form.
     *
     * @param  array   $options
     * @return string
     */
    public function open(array $options = array())
    {
        // If you haven't specified an autocomplete option, default it to 'off'
        if(!isset($options['autocomplete'])) {
            $options['autocomplete'] = 'off';
        }

        return parent::open($options);
    }
}
```

Next, you will need to create a service provider that extends from `Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider` and override the `registerFormBuilder` method:

```
use Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider;
use MyForm;

class FormServiceProvider extends HtmlServiceProvider
{
    public function registerFormBuilder()
    {
        $app = $this->app;
        // Taken From: Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider
        $app->bindShared('form', function($app) {
            // Replace FormBuilder with MyForm
            $form = new MyForm($app['html'], $app['url'], $app['session.store']->getToken());

            return $form->setSessionStore($app['session.store']);
        });
    }
}
```

Finally, you will need to replace `'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',` in `app/config/app.php` with your new Service Provider.  I have tested this on a local test Laravel 4.2 install and works without having to modify anything in the calls to `Form::open`

Comment: Nice!! I wish there was a less hackish solution, but still awesome :)

Comment: I don't see how this is hackish. You're extending a built in class and creating a custom service provider. What's hackish about that?

Answer (score 1):

I was feeling lazy, so I just added the line `$attributes['autocomplete'] = 'off';` to the file `FormBuilder.php`. I added it on line # 108 in the open function.

This is a good example of a hacky solution.